# How can I set autoplay to a vimeo video using embed tag?

Tags: php, html, laravel, vimeo

I have the following embed tag in my html file

```
    <embed src='{{"https://player.vimeo.com/video/{$videouri}?autoplay=true"}}'width="300" height="361" />
```

Im having some trouble using the '?autoplay=true' and the '.play'(javascript). They just wont work for me.
Any ideas on how to make it work?

Comment: Try add `allow="autoplay"` to your embed (like your width/height attributes) https://vimeo.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/115004485728-Autoplaying-and-looping-embedded-videos

Comment: Which kind of "trouble" do you have?

Comment: @NicoHaase , using '?autoplay=true' it doesnt work all the time ,

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't work"? What should happen? And what do you mean by that `.play`?

Comment: @NicoHaase it should autostart the video (?). vimeo has a tool that (I THINK) you can import to your project so you can call functions, it would look like Vimeo.play().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I look to the official Vimeo documentation this pops up:

```
<iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/{{ $videouri }}?autoplay=true" width="300" height="361" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay"></iframe>
```

It looks like you have to add the following things:

- Add `?autoplay=1` to the url (what you already did)
- Add `allow="autoplay"` to the iframe element

Not sure if this also work for `<embed>` element.

> side-note: If you use Laravel Blade you just can leave the url normal and add `{{ $videouri }}` to the url instead of double quoting the url and variable.

Comment: Im using this to code a MikroTik hotspot, and for some reason it doesnt accept iframe neither the html video tag. Thats why I had to use embed.  The '?autoplay=true' sometimes works fine and sometimes it doesn't.

Comment: You should check the browser console, not sure which browser you are using. But this issue sounds like "Autoplay Policy". In major browsers the user have to click on something once to remove the autoplay prevention. (side-note: also add details like MikroTik hotspot to your question, so people can beter understand your question)